# Get bound events for wxwidget?

Tags: widget, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxperl

I would like to be able to determine all methods bound to events for a particular wxwidget.

I am binding my events dynamically. Is there a way to determine which methods i have bound to each event type available to my wxwidget further down the line, with just a reference to the widget?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread, wxPython cannot expose that information: http://www.mentby.com/Group/wxpython-users/where-isare-the-bind-ings-lists-stored.html

Instead, Robin Dunn (author of wxPython) recommends overriding Bind and storing the information that way or use PubSub instead.